# PHP mcrypt and REMI

Tags: php, centos6, mcrypt

Am running PHP56 from REMI and need to use mcrypt for an old script to work - I am running REMI PHP56:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /opt/remi/php56/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.ini
```

and I have installed mcrypt:

```
Package php-mcrypt-5.6.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

However, there is no ini file for mcrypt and it is not listed as a PHP module:

```
php56 -m
[PHP Modules]
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
```

What am I missing? What else do I need to do to enable mcrypt?

Comment: you can try ``php5enmod mcrypt`` on console. don't forget restart the apache.

Comment: php5enmod is a debian only tool, with RPM, installed = enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 PHP stacks installed.

- php-* (default version, in /usr)
- php56-php-* (parallel installable version, in /opt)

According to phpinfo information, the second is used, so you need **php56-php-mcrypt**.

For installation instruction, see the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).